# how to show network image ( also customize this image) as marker in map flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[image]

I'm using this code, but this is only for showing network image
but I also needed to customise the images, like this(i added demo image as above ).

link-
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60201433/10253151

Code-

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

          var iconurl ="your url";
          var dataBytes;
          var request = await http.get(iconurl);
          var bytes = await request.bodyBytes;

          setState(() {
            dataBytes = bytes;
          });

          LatLng _lastMapPositionPoints = LatLng(
              double.parse("22.7339"),
              double.parse("75.8499"));

            _markers.add(Marker(
              icon: BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(dataBytes.buffer.asUint8List()),
              markerId: MarkerId(_lastMapPositionPoints.toString()),
              position: _lastMapPositionPoints,
              infoWindow: InfoWindow(
                title: "Delivery Point",
                snippet:
                "My Position",
              ),
            ));
```

Answer (score 4):

Google map Marker icon only accepts Icons and Bitmap images. So first you need to convert the url images to Bitmap images.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
import 'dart:io';
Map<String, Uint8List> userIdMarkerMap = {};
Future getMarkerImage() async
  {

    for(int j=0;j<userIdList.length;j++) {
      final File markerImageFile = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(imageURL);
      final Uint8List markerImageBytes = await markerImageFile.readAsBytes();


      ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(markerImageBytes, targetWidth: 50);
      ui.FrameInfo fi = await codec.getNextFrame();

      final Uint8List markerImage = (await fi.image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png)).buffer.asUint8List();

      userIdMarkerMap[userIdList[j]] = markerImage;

    }

    setState(() {
      //call your function to build google map
    });

  }
```

then you can use this from google map marker.

```
      markers.add(Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId(userIdList[j]),
      position: LatLng(lat, lon),
      icon: userIdMarkerMap[userIdList[j]] != null ? BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(userIdMarkerMap[userIdList[j]]) : BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,));
```

Comment: this is resize image,but i needed that,marker type icon center place image..
for example , i added image in question.

Comment: you need to have the marker+user_image on your url. That means the url should have the marker image with user image.

Comment: any way we can add those images inside a widget and then use it as market ?

Comment: also please import this import 'dart:ui' as ui;

Answer (score 3):

**1. How to add the network image in marker**

**2. How to resize the network image**

```
    import 'dart:io';
    import 'dart:ui' as ui;
    import 'dart:typed_data';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
    import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';



    static Future<BitmapDescriptor> getMarkerImageFromUrl(
     String url, {
     int targetWidth,
      }) async {
    assert(url != null);
    final File markerImageFile = await 
       DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
    if (targetWidth != null) {
      return ImageUtils.convertImageFileToBitmapDescriptor(markerImageFile,
          size: targetWidth);
    } else {
      Uint8List markerImageBytes = await markerImageFile.readAsBytes();
      return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(markerImageBytes);
    }
    }




     static Future<BitmapDescriptor> convertImageFileToBitmapDescriptor(
      File imageFile,
      {int size = 100,
      bool addBorder = false,
      Color borderColor = Colors.white,
      double borderSize = 10,
      Color titleColor = Colors.transparent,
      Color titleBackgroundColor = Colors.transparent}) async {
    final ui.PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
    final Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
    final Paint paint = Paint()..color;
    final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    );
       final double radius = size / 2;

    //make canvas clip path to prevent image drawing over the circle
    final Path clipPath = Path();
    clipPath.addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.toDouble(), size.toDouble()),
        Radius.circular(100)));
    clipPath.addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromLTWH(size / 2.toDouble(), size + 20.toDouble(), 10, 10),
        Radius.circular(100)));
    canvas.clipPath(clipPath);

    //paintImage
    final Uint8List imageUint8List = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
    final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(imageUint8List);
    final ui.FrameInfo imageFI = await codec.getNextFrame();
    paintImage(
        canvas: canvas,
        rect: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.toDouble(), size.toDouble()),
        image: imageFI.image);

    //convert canvas as PNG bytes
    final _image = await pictureRecorder
        .endRecording()
        .toImage(size, (size * 1.1).toInt());
    final data = await _image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

    //convert PNG bytes as BitmapDescriptor
    return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
    }
    }
```

Comment: This is good. But can you make marker with circular image in it?